# Error deploying site definition through a script

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have made a simple site definition project in which I have set Pre-deployment and Post Deployment script which are as follows:

Pre-Deployment :

```
iisreset
```

Post-Deployment :

```
stsadm -o deletesite http://my-pc:35502/
stsadm -o createsite http://my-pc:35502/ -owneremail admin@nowhere.com -ownerlogin mybase\rogertest -sitetemplate SiteDefinitionProject2#0 -title "Test1"
```

But it is giving me the error

> exited with error code: 9009.

Comment: I might suggest that you add the full path to the stsadm command as it is not likely resolving the location of the stsadm application.  I think it is a bad idea to put site deletion/creation commands into the build events like this.

Comment: I am following the appdev tutorials way.

Comment: Adding full path to stsadm didnt work either.